# It is possible to connect galaxy watch web application to un existing PWA in node js that is not created with tizen ide?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, tizen, samsung-galaxy-gear

I need to creates un web app for galaxy watch and connect it to an pwa in node js companion that it exist already.

This pwa companion its not created with tizen tools.

So I would like to know if its possible to make connection in a direct way or i have to create new pwa companion with tizen tools ?

Thanks

Comment: Could you let us know the purpose of connection between an web app for galaxy and a pwa companion? e.g.) to exchange data or to launch an application or etc..

Comment: Hi. The thing is that I already have a pwa to manage sports sessions and I would like to recover the biometric data generated (e.g heartbeats) by the watch to send them to the pwa made in node js, to be able to save them in the database.